# Google Sheets Split remove characters and unwanted words

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this data as a sample in a column:

```
3 PACK BAG 1500 ML CONTAIN 600 ML AMINO ACID, 600 ML GLUCOSE, 300 ML LIPID EMULSION
```

I am using this formula to remove unwanted characters: `=SPLIT(A2:A,"1234567890-=[]\;',./!@#$%^&*()")`

So it returns me:

```
 PACK BAG    ML C   NTAIN    ML AMIN     ACID        ML GLUC    SE       ML LIPID EMULSI    N
```

Now i would like to add in my formula `=SPLIT(A2:A,"1234567890-=[]\;',./!@#$%^&*()")` a function to remove "MC" and "C" OR "SE".

How i can update my formula split to remove the specific chain of characters (words) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "(MC|C|SE)", " "),"1234567890-=[]\;',./!@#$%^&*()")
```

You could pre-process your string with REGEXREPLACE to substitute a specific character (eg. whitespace) for these specific words before applying the SPLIT function.

Comment: This formula will remove all the ''C''. So now it will remove the ''C'' from PACK BAG. I want to remove the exact string ''MC'' or ''C'' unique. I want to keep PACK BAG untouch.

Comment: it's not clear to me exactly what you are after, but if you want to remove all the " C " (note the whitespaces around the C), you could use "(MC| C |SE)". (and you could similarly add whitespaces around the MC and SE).